# D3 composite key function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is it possible to join data with a composite key function? I'd like to join ranked employee objects using a composite of their name and rank such that swapping two employees' ranks and rejoining results in their inclusion in both the exit selection and the entry selection (as opposed to just the update selection). I tried:

```js
var myData = [{"Rank":1,"Team Member":"John Smag","Ships":48},{"Rank":2,"Team Member":"Leslie Kwarki","Ships":46},{"Rank":3,"Team Member":"Jasmine Doublet","Ships":32}];

function log(selection, action) {
  console.log(action, selection[0].length);
}
function join() {
  var selection = d3.select('body').selectAll('p').data(myData, function(d) {
   return d['Team Member'] + d['Rank'];
  });
  selection.each(function(d) {
    console.log('updating', d);
  });
  selection.enter().append('p').text(function(d) {
    return d['Ships'];
  }).each(function(d) {
    console.log('entering', d);
  });
  selection.exit().remove().each(function(d) {
    console.log('exiting', d);
  });
}

join();
var temp = myData[1]['Rank'];
myData[1]['Rank'] = myData[2]['Rank'];
myData[2]['Rank'] = temp;
join();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A composite key function does work, that's not the problem here.

The problem is the way that you're changing your data array before calling `join` again. Have a look at this demo, where the whole object is changed, you'll see that the "enter", "update" and "exit" selections work as you expect:

```js
var myData = [{
  "Rank": 1,
  "Team Member": "John Smag",
  "Ships": 48
}, {
  "Rank": 2,
  "Team Member": "Leslie Kwarki",
  "Ships": 46
}, {
  "Rank": 3,
  "Team Member": "Jasmine Doublet",
  "Ships": 32
}];

function log(selection, action) {
  console.log(action, selection[0].length);
}

function join() {
  var selection = d3.select('body').selectAll('p').data(myData, function(d) {
    return d['Team Member'] + d['Rank'];
  });
  selection.each(function(d) {
    console.log('updating', d);
  });
  selection.enter().append('p').text(function(d) {
    return d['Ships'];
  }).each(function(d) {
    console.log('entering', d);
  });
  selection.exit().remove().each(function(d) {
    console.log('exiting', d);
  });
}

join();
var temp = myData[1];
myData[1] = {
  "Rank": 3,
  "Team Member": "Leslie Kwarki",
  "Ships": 46
};
myData[2] = {
  "Rank": 2,
  "Team Member": "Jasmine Doublet",
  "Ships": 32
};
join();
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As for the first question, Is it possible to join data with a composite key function? Yes. You are doing it.

As for the second question, an element can't be both in the enter selection and the exit selection. The enter selection is for elements that don't exist and need to be added. The exit selection is for those that exist but no longer match the data. In d3, those sets will be exclusive. I am not sure why the update selection is not meeting your needs.

Comment: The update selection is wrong because there are two unique keys in the second call to `join()` that didn't exist previously.